# Hosting Parse on Azure - Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, parse-platform

**EDIT:** I have enabled logging, here is the error in more detail:

```
Uncaught internal server error. { [MongoError: Authentication failed.]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'Authentication failed.',
ok: 0,
code: 18,
```

I've been following the Microsoft Azure guide to setting up Parse on Azure, which is [here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/)

I've completed the steps and have everything up and running, however, when I try to create a new account on my Obj-C app, I get the error `[Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)`.

I'm not sure why this happens, as I can see on Azure that I am getting multiple requests and HTTP errors.

Also the parse source I'm using is the one Azure have provided/forked, so maybe that's where the error is coming from?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you enable logging and show us the error message on the server side? Could be a lot of things...

Comment: @TobiahZarlez Sorry about that! Check my edit. Is it possible I'm getting this error because I have my MongoLab credentials wrong? e.g. `mongodb://username123:password123@ds6666.mongolab.com:6666/myapp`

Comment: Can you double-check the MongoDB credentials? Seems like the most likely point of failure.

Comment: Where did you enable Logging on azure?

Answer (score 2):

The error is with your MongoDB authentication. Double check you followed the steps correctly for the Parse on Azure tutorial, so that there isn't any hard coded incorrect "username/password123" strings

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the URI is correct.  I had some issues when migrating.  If you use the [Parse Server Managed on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/), it creates the server for you and you can check the Database URI structure there.  (In the web app - application settings - DATABASE_URI)

You can also open the settings of the documentDB and check the URI settings there.

Another trick is that if you change the DATABASE_URI setting (in application settings) make sure you restart your web app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added "/parse" at the end of your URL