# Password reset with Parse on Azure & Postmark

Tags: azure, parse-server, postmark

I have migrated data from the parse website to Azure's version of parse and notice some components were missing like an email adapter. So I follow the instructions from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-postmark-adapter. I'm able to receive email to change my password.

But I get this error when I click on the link to change my password,

"level":"error","message":"Uncaught internal server error. [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this message? Also, I put the code to configure postmark in my config.js file.

Edit:

```
var PostmarkAdapter = require('parse-server-postmark-adapter');

module.exports = {
  server: {
      appName: 'myapp',
      publicServerURL: 'http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/parse',
      verifyUserEmails: true, // Enable email verification 
      emailAdapter: PostmarkAdapter({
          apiKey: 'api-key-0000',
          fromAddress: 'someemail@email.com',
      })

    },
  dashboard: {},
  storage: {},
  push: {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Zachary!  Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373702/hosting-parse-on-azure-internal-server-error/35386553

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Hi @ZacharyJamison , it looks like, based on your description that the error you're getting is when you click on a link in an email that was processed by Postmark. Can you confirm that the link works prior to sending it using Postmark?

Comment: Also, @ZacharyJamison, the error you mentioned usually indicates that the HTTP endpoint is sending the response body before the headers for the response are set. A common case where this happens is if you stream a file or other content and then set the content type and other headers. You'll need to set the headers before writing any file content for the endpoint.

Comment: @Andrew Theken When putting the link in the url, it goes to goes to the password rest page but I'm still getting the error. Can you also specify a bit more on the second paragraph.

Comment: @ZacharyJamison I don't think this error is related to postmark. If you can post the source code for the password reset method on your server, then we can probably point out the error.